# Display QGIS Temporal Controller widget within custom plugin widget

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qt, temporal-controller

I am building a QGIS-Plugin retrieving time-series raster data from several sources, which is then supposed to be visualized (so far separately and manually) via the Temporal Controller widget, added in QGIS 3.14.

So far, I am opening the Temporal Controller on plugin startup via

```
        for i in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QtWidgets.QDockWidget):
          if i.objectName() == 'Temporal Controller':
            i.setVisible(True)
```

For user convenience, I am trying to add the Temporal Controller widget within my custom widget, which contains the other functions of my plugin. I.e. the Temporal Controller is simply supposed to be displayed as-is within my plugin's own UI.

Unfortunately, I have so far only worked using Qt Designer, and my experience building a UI from code is very limited. I have not found an example that this is possible.

Is it at all possible to import an existing widget into another widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this fairly straightforward to do, although examples aren't necessarily easy to find.
Some examples of a layout without the Qt designer can be found in the crayfish plugin:
https://github.com/lutraconsulting/qgis-crayfish-plugin/blob/master/crayfish/gui/plot_3d_widget.py

For reference, the documentation of the Temporal Controller widget can be found here:
https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.14/gui/QgsTemporalControllerWidget.html

Here's an example:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout
from qgis.gui import QgsTemporalControllerWidget


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
 
        self.temporal_controller = QgsTemporalControllerWidget()
        self.push_button = QPushButton("Click me!")
        self.push_button.clicked.connect(self.f)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.temporal_controller)
        layout.addWidget(self.push_button)
         
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def f(self):
        # Does nothing, just for illustration
        return
```

Basically, every object you have available in the Qt Designer is available here.
You can use the `.addWidget` methods, `.addLayout`, and `.setLayout` to build your menus without the Qt designer. These are PyQt5 Widgets, so that's where you'd have to look for the documentation.

As a general note, I'm expecting this temporal controller to be a separate instance, so I don't think it will stay in sync with the "default" temporal controller. You could probably write some methods to get them to sync though.